# Why does LinkGenerator always return null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have written a class to generate links for other classes (Aspnet core 3.1) which send emails with links in them which gets an instance of LinkGenerator via DI.

Whenever I call any method on the instance of LinkGenerator, it returns null. Am I doing something wrong?

```
 public interface IPageLinkGenerator
    {
        string LinkFor(string page, object values);
    }

    public class PageLinkGenerator : IPageLinkGenerator
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
        private readonly LinkGenerator _generator;

        public PageLinkGenerator(IHttpContextAccessor accessor, LinkGenerator generator)
        {
            _accessor = accessor;
            _generator = generator;
        }

        public string LinkFor(string page, object values)
        {
            var context = _accessor.HttpContext;

            var callBackLink = _generator.GetUriByPage(
                context,
                page: page,
                handler: null,
                values: values,
                scheme: context.Request.Scheme,
                host: context.Request.Host
                );

            return callBackLink;
        }
    }
```

This is my ConfigureServices method from Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureContainer(ServiceRegistry services)
        {
            services.Scan(_ =>
            {
                _.AssemblyContainingType<IDbConnectionFactory>();
                _.WithDefaultConventions();
                _.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IHandle<>));
            });

            services.For<IConfiguration>().Use(Configuration);
            services.For<IStorageClient>().Use<AzureBlobClient>();
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddSingleton<IDomainEventDispatcher, DomainEventDispatcher>();
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IAsyncRepository<>), typeof(EfRepository<>));
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IValidationRepository<>), typeof(ValidationRepository<>));
            
            services.AddCustomisedDbContext(Configuration);
            services.AddHtmlTags(new TagConventions());
            services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup));

            services.For<IRazorLightEngine>()
                .Use(RazorLightEngineFactory.Get())
                .Singleton();

            services.AddTestConfigurationInstance(_environment, Configuration);
            services.AddEmailSender(_environment);

            services.AddProxyHttpClient();

            services.AddCustomisedIdentity(_environment, Configuration);

            services.AddAuthorizationPolicies(Configuration);

            services.AddCustomisedRazorPages();

            services.AddWkhtmltopdf();

            services.AddLocalization();
            
            services.AddRouting();
        }
```

This is the method which calls the class:

```
public async Task Handle(BookingAdminMessageCreated @event, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var url = _linkGenerator.LinkFor("/Customers/Bookings/Messages", new { Id = @event.BookingId.ToString() });
        
        foreach (var (fullName, emailAddress) in @event.EmailDetails)
        {
            await _emailSender.SendAsync(emailAddress, MailType.MessageAdded, new Dictionary<string, dynamic>
            {
                {"FullName", fullName},
                {"ReferenceNumber", @event.Reference},
                {"BookingUrl", HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(url)},
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how you call the PageLinkGenerator ? Do you register it as a service?

Comment: I'm using Lamar which registers it as a service and injects it into another class via DI.

Comment: The LinkGenerator servides will be registered when you call the services.AddRouting();, since I don't know the lamar will register the addrouting serivce. You could try to register it and try again. Besides, please share your  codes like startup.cs as @CodeCaster says.

Comment: @BrandoZhang I've added services.AddRouting() to the startup.cs and LinkGenerator still returns null

Comment: It seems that you don't register the PageLinkGenerator as service in the ConfigureContainer method.

Comment: @BrandoZhang _.WithDefaultConventions() takes care of that. That is not the issue, the issue is the _generator.GetUriByPage() always returns null in the PageLinkGenerator class.

Comment: When you will call the GetUriByPage? Please share related codes.

Comment: @BrandoZhang I have updated the question with the code

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was missing out the page name in the page. I wasn't specifying the Index page.

```
_linkGenerator.LinkFor("/Customers/Bookings/Messages/Index" ...
```